# SQL Server - Sequence creation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

This is with SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

Our requirement is, the procedure should insert the unique sequence in my table and the inserted value should be returned to the output.

I do not have any issues most of the time.

But in rarest situation, when the procedure is called by different threads at the same time, (just differ by very few milliseconds), we getting same value returned (duplicate).

My procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNewID]
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @NEWSEQVALUE INT
      DECLARE @INSERTEDROWS AS TABLE (NewID INT)

      SET NOCOUNT ON

      INSERT INTO NewID 
      OUTPUT INSERTED.NewID INTO @INSERTEDROWS VALUES ('A', GETDATE())
          SELECT @NEWSEQVALUE = NewID 
          FROM @INSERTEDROWS

      RETURN @NEWSEQVALUE
END
```

My table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NewID ]
(
    [NewID] [int] IDENTITY(1000000,1) NOT NULL,
    [SeqVal] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [Createdate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

SQL Server version we are using is - SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3.

Any suggestions to overcome this ?

Comment: Have you tried using transaction?

Comment: Is it possible you could add a primary key or unique constraint?

Comment: As you have found out yourself, having a column defined as `IDENTITY` doesn't guarantee that there will be no duplicate values. Creating a unique index on this column does guarantee that there will be no duplicate values.

Comment: "we getting same value returned" means you find duplicate values in the table. If not, check your threads (are thread-safe?)